# how to use tickInterval or step in the highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

For example

If i want set the Categories,i can write this code

chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(list.time);

then i want set tickInterval or step in the highcharts

how to use?

Comment: can you elaborate your question some more? May be give some better example

Answer (score 0):

First set the axis' tick interval to null, in the options object.

Then you can set it programmatically: http://livecoding.gabrielflor.it/3351635

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please make sure to accept it.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work any more... can you maybe put it in a JSFiddle?